# Animating constraint on a pair of views (or keeping content constraints within an animating view)

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, swift2

I'm coding in Swift 2.0 with Xcode.

I have a UITableView that has a constraint to the top of the view. It is also constrained to the other 3 edges of the view but only the top constraint varies.

A label is then paired with the table with top/bottom/left/right constraints so it exactly relates to the size and position of the tableview.

I am animating the table constraint with the following code.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
self.myTableViewTop.constant = 300
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     }) { (completed) -> Void in
        // process completion stuff here
}
```

I expected that the label that is tied to all dimensions of the table would resize in accordance to the animating table size but it doesn't seem to.

What happens is the label reverts immediately to its final size and waits for the animated table to catch up.

What am I missing here? Something to do with priorities? Or a different way to tie the 2 elements together? Or do I need to animate both at same time?

Thanks.

Comment: I thought I'd come up with a solution by putting both the label and table in a view and only dealing with the view top constraint - but it makes no difference whatsoever so I'm now even more confused

Comment: Strange, but for me it works fine. When do you run animation?

Comment: Thx Nikita - that's both good and bad news.. :) The animation is run via a longPress on a different UIView which also has a Tap Gesture assigned. Following your confirmation that this isn't a quirk that needs to be dealt with, I'll check other constraints and gestures for conflicts